# nonparametric method to calculate the probability how alike two samples are

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling, nonparametric, inference

I have two samples with each couple of hunderd observations. I want to calculate a probabilty how much they look alike. I'm aware of tests like kolmogorov smirnov but I don't think I need this. I don't want to test if they come from different distributions. I'm actually want to show that they come from the same (continuous) distribution.

I looked around a bit on the internet, but I'm not sure how to approach this. Do I need bootstrapping? Also, I'm using R, so pointers to usefull packages are welcome.

thanks in advance

**update:**
As commented below, you can not really prove there are from a simmilar distribution. So the question would rather be, how can I assign a degree of belief that they are from the same distribution?

Comment: This cannot be done.  You can quantify the *degree of similarity* between two data distributions and you can *test a null hypothesis* that they are samples of the same population, but you can never *prove* they came from the same population (unless both were exhaustive samples of a finite population in the first place!).

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question according to your remarks. SO the question would be how do I assign a degree of belief to their simmilarity?

Comment: Could Kullback–Leibler divergence help?

Answer (score 0):

Without a bit more detail it's difficult to know for sure what you need, but assuming you have two independent samples that are continuous data, a Mann-Whitney U test is a statistical significance test to test if two populations are the same.

There's an article on carrying out the test here:
http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/non-parametric-methods/mann-whitney-wilcoxon-test

You can do the test with the *stats* package, so if you need to install it:

```
install.packages("stats"); library(stats)
```

Then, assuming your data looks something like this:

```
s1 <- runif(10); s2 <- runif(10)
View(d)
```

I.e. samples are separate vectors, you can run a version of the test with the following basic syntax:

```
wilcox.test(s1, s2)
```

If, instead, you have a dataframe that has all the observations in one column and another column to specify the sample the observation belongs to:

```
s <- runif(10)
f <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
d <- data.frame(s, f)
View(d)
```

then you would use the ~ syntax:

```
wilcox.test(d$s ~ d$f)
```

Hope this is helpful. Don't forget to mark your question answered if this solves your problem, or post further details if it doesn't!

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Doesn't this test only allow you to prove that 2 samples have different distributions. If you cannot reject the null hypothesis (= same distributions), you have no proof that the null hypothesis can be rejected. This is not the same as proofing that the null hypothesis is true. You just don't know if its true or not.

Comment: The U test only tests whether one distribution is stochastically greater than the other, *not* whether they are the same.

Comment: For about 200 observations in each group, should one not do an unpaired t-test? Or check their distribution and if it is normal, do an unpaired t-test?

Comment: Yup, I've misinterpreted what you were asking for. I know of no way to test if two samples are from one population.

Comment: @rnso, assuming you wanted to carry out the test, I would add a paired = F arguement if the two samples were independent, or leave the default paired = T if the observations were paired in some way, yes. I wasn't sure about the nature of the observations. But as I was on the wrong track anyway...!